# Dependencies installation error for React

Tags: reactjs

While I am trying to install dependencies for the client, as below, the following errors were shown. What does it mean and how can I resolve it?

```
npm install axios moment react-file-base64 redux redux-thunk
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.2" from react-file-base64@1.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-file-base64
npm ERR!   react-file-base64@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/owen/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: react-file-base64 depends on react 15, but you depend on react 17. try: a) downgrading or b) running it with --force

Comment: Thank you Logan. I tried installing it by adding --force and apparently it can be installed. Hope that there will not be any conflicting issues due to my React version.

Comment: I've made it into an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer from my comment:

> react-file-base64 depends on react 15, but you depend on react 17. try: a) downgrading or b) running it with --force

The fix: run with --force